# Directory of BOOST_BUILD_PATH

Tags: c++, boost

I intend to work with owlcpp ([owl-cpp](https://owl-cpp.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html)) and in the installation process I need to install Boost. I am working on the version of ubuntu 18.04.

When I try to run the example for testing:

```
b2 release
```

I have this error:

```
   'boost-build /usr/include/boost ;'

but we were unable to find "bootstrap.jam" in the specified directory
or in BOOST_BUILD_PATH (searching /usr/include/boost, /usr/share/boost-build).
```

When I install or Boost generated header file is in /usr/local/lib/boost/include, and the binary library file is in /usr/local/lib/boost/lib

I checked the installation and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you download boost to your local directory (/usr/local/boost_1_76_0, for example), you will find these jam files, incl. boost-build.jam).

You can build from right here using bootstrap.sh; then you can run b2 install to install binaries to their usual places.

You can also set an environment variable yourself (with the suggested name BOOST_BUILD_PATH) to point to /usr/local/boost_1_76_0/tools/build, in your .bashrc or .profile file.)